# Show that the equation cos 2x = 5sinx - 2 giving all solutions in the range 0 ≤ x ≤ π

Tags: trigonometry

Solve $\cos(2x) = 5\sin(x) - 2$ for $x\in[0,\pi]$.

Attempt:

$$\cos(2x) - 5\sin(x) = -2
$$
$$x(cos2 - 5sin) = -2
$$
$$x(0.99- 0.087) = -2
$$
$$0.903x  = -2
$$
$$X = 2.22
$$

$$Cos 2 = 0.99
$$
$$Sin5 = 0.087$$

Please is this right? I'm getting one answer and the question says solutions.

Comment: $\cos 2x\ne x\cos 2$ and $\sin$ alone does not have a "number" value.

Comment: Okay. That means I did it wrong. Can you please expansiate

Comment: The whole approach is blatantly wrong. First try to understand what  are $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding $\cos{2x}$ as $1-2\sin^2{x}$ (by the double-angle formula and $\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}=1$), we have
$$ 1-2\sin^2{x} = 5\sin{x}-2, $$
or
$$ 0 = 2\sin^2{x}+5\sin{x}-3 = (2\sin{x}-1)(\sin{x}+3), $$
factorising the quadratic. $\sin{x}$ is between $-1$ and $1$ for any real $x$, so the solutions can be only be given by
$$ \sin{x} = \frac{1}{2}. $$
There are two solutions to this for which $0 \leqslant x \leqslant \pi$: $x=\pi/6$ and $x=5\pi/6$, which can be seen by drawing a plot of the sine function.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Chappers. I get all but I don't understand how you got x=π/6 and x=5π/6